# How to update string values with incrementing numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a table that has a column which needs to be updated with values like

```
dummy1
dummy2
dummy3
..
..
..
dummy6
```

I created the following while loop script

```
create table people_test(UserName varchar(40))
GO

INSERT INTO people_test (UserName) values ('admin'),('test'),('opq'),('mn'),('ijkl'),('efgh'),('abcd')
GO

Select * from people_test
GO

DECLARE @i int;
DECLARE @j int = 1;
BEGIN
    SELECT @i = COUNT(*) FROM people_test WHERE username <> 'admin';

    WHILE(@j <= @i)
        BEGIN
            print 'i='+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i)+' j='+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j);
            UPDATE people_test
              SET 
                  UserName = 'dummy'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j)
            WHERE username <> 'admin';
            print 'i='+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i)+' j='+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j);
            SET @j = @j + 1;
        END;
END;
GO
```

***Expected result***

| UserName |
| --- |
| admin |
| dummy1 |
| dummy2 |
| dummy3 |

***Result that I am seeing***

| UserName |
| --- |
| admin |
| dummy6 |
| dummy6 |
| dummy6 |

Comment: Which column provides the _order_ for assigning `dummy1`, `dummy2`, etc., sequence values?

Comment: The `where` clause on the `update` changes _all_ of the non-"admin" rows to the _same_ value. Aside: Best practice is to _always_ provide a length for variable-length types, e.g. `VarChar`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - for sorting i have an id column. This is a sample script to showcase my issue.

Comment: @DaleK - my print shows the values as

i=6 j=1

(6 rows affected)
i=6 j=1
i=6 j=2


(6 rows affected)
i=6 j=2
i=6 j=3


(6 rows affected)
i=6 j=3
i=6 j=4

(6 rows affected)
i=6 j=4
i=6 j=5

(6 rows affected)
i=6 j=5
i=6 j=6

(6 rows affected)
i=6 j=6

Completion time: 2021-02-09T09:59:28.8045037+05:30

Comment: @DaleK - sorry for the format, but Stackoverflow does not allow me to put in newline

Comment: You should [edit] that info into your question, not try and add it in a comment.

Comment: so how do i alter my query to update the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this task with the `row_number()` function and therefore without a loop. Something like this:

```
drop table if exists #people_test 
go
create table #people_test  (UserName varchar (1000))
go
INSERT INTO #people_test (UserName) values ('admin'),('test'),('opq'),('mn'),('ijkl'),('efgh'),('abcd')
GO

update t
    set t.UserName = 'dummy' + cast(t.rn as varchar(10))
from (
    select row_number() over (order by UserName ) rn, * 
    from #people_test
    where UserName!='admin'
) t

select * from #people_test
order by UserName
```

Comment: i can not drop the table.

Comment: @SuwaidAkbar this is just an example for testing the query, of course, you don't need to drop the table and create it again in your real case.

Comment: @dzhukov its recommended best practice **not** to use `order by 1` but rather the column name.

Comment: This worked as well. Thanks a lot @dzhukov and Dale K

Comment: @DaleK accepted, but in everyday life, sometimes it's too lazy to write the column name, especially when you need to quickly get a temporary result and foget it.

Comment: @dzhukov sure, but when providing answers to newbies on this site you should always aim to use best practices as they will assume you are.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table people_test(USERID int,UserName varchar(40))
GO

INSERT INTO people_test (USERID, UserName) values (1,'admin'),(2,'test'),(3,'opq'),(4,'mn'),(5,'ijkl'),(6,'efgh'),(7,'abcd')
GO

Select * from people_test
GO

DECLARE @i int;
DECLARE @j int = 1;
DECLARE @k int;

DECLARE c_id cursor for
Select USERID from PEOPLE_TEST
WHERE username <> 'admin'

BEGIN

open c_id;
FETCH NEXT FROM c_id into @k

    SELECT @i = COUNT(*) FROM PEOPLE_TEST WHERE username <> 'admin';

    WHILE(@j <= @i)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE PEOPLE_TEST
              SET 
                  UserName = concat('dummy',@j)
                  WHERE userid = @k;
            print 'i='+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@i)+' j='+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j)+' k='+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@k);
            SET @j = @j + 1;
            FETCH NEXT FROM c_id into @k
        END;
close c_id
Deallocate c_id
END;

Select * from people_test
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMPS','U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMPS

create table #TEMPS (UserName varchar(40))
GO
INSERT INTO #TEMPS (UserName) values ('admin'),('test'),('opq'),('mn'),('ijkl'),('efgh'),('abcd')
GO

UPDATE T1  SET T1.USERNAME= 'DUMMY'+CAST(T2.ROW AS varchar)
FROM #TEMPS AS T1, (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY USERNAME) AS ROW,*  FROM #TEMPS ) AS T2
WHERE T2.UserName=T1.UserName AND T1.UserName!='ADMIN'

SELECT * FROM #TEMPS ORDER BY 1

Answer (score 1):

Your own solution might work, but this is the wrong century for a CURSOR/LOOP based solution for such an easy task. Try something along this:

--Create a test table and fill it with data.

```
CREATE TABLE people_test(USERID INT IDENTITY,UserName VARCHAR(40))
GO

INSERT INTO people_test (UserName) VALUES 
 ('admin')
,('test')
,('opq')
,('mn')
,('ijkl')
,('efgh')
,('abcd');
GO

SELECT * FROM people_test;
GO
```

--This is an *updateable CTE*

```
WITH upd AS
(
    SELECT UserName
          ,CONCAT(UserName,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY USERID)) AS NewUserName
    FROM people_test
    WHERE UserName <> 'admin'
)
UPDATE upd SET UserName=NewUserName;
GO
```

--See the result

```
SELECT * FROM people_test;
GO
```

--Clean-up (carefull with real data!)

```
DROP TABLE people_test;
GO
```

The idea in short:

- The CTE `upd` will return two columns:

  - `UserName` is the column you want to change
  - `NewUserName` is a computed column returning the value you want to see in UserName.
- We can simply use `UPDATE upd` to update the *underlying* table.

Comment: Thanks @shnugo - I tried the similar way and got it updated...thanks